# Redirect in react router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have defined routing in my application like

```
            <Route path="/settings/*" element={<AccountSettings />}>
```

and in one of my components I defined another route like

```
 <Route
          path="security"
          element={< Example />>
```

Everything is being routed correctly, in this example /settings/security
However I want user to be redirected to /settings/profile whenever user hits this component?

Is there a way to default the routing to be /settings/profile? (I've tried useEffect but that seems very inefficient)

Comment: What is `"/settings/profile"` and where do you want the redirect to occur? Are you saying you want the `"/settings/security"` path to just redirect to `"/settings/profile"` directly?

Comment: I want the /settings to redirect to /settings/profile when user hits this component(/settings)

Comment: Is this something that `AccountSettings` needs to do? Can you include all relevant code you are trying to work with in your post as a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? So far I've gathered that there's a parent route rendering `AccountSettings` and this component is likely rendering a `Routes` component with descendent `Route` components, and you want to redirect to, or default to, one of these routes. Is this correct? Can we see more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
        <Route path="/settings/*" element={<AccountSettings />}></Route>
        <Route
          path="/settings"
          element={<Navigate to="./profile" />}
        ></Route>
```